# Getting error slicing time series with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I'm trying to slice a time series, I can do it perfectly this way :

```
subseries = series['2015-07-07 01:00:00':'2015-07-07 03:30:00'] .
```

But the following code won't work

```
def GetDatetime():

    Y = int(raw_input("Year "))
    M = int(raw_input("Month "))
    D = int(raw_input("Day "))
    d = datetime.datetime(Y, M, D) #creates a datetime object
    return d

filePath = "pathtofile.csv"
series = pd.read_csv(str(filePath), index_col='date') 
series.index = pd.to_datetime(series.index, unit='s')

d = GetDatetime()
f = GetDatetime()

subseries = series[d:f]
```

The last line generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dontgivemeerrorsbrasommek.py", line 37, in <module>
    brasla7nina= df[d:f]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1952, in __getitem__
    indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1896, in convert_to_index_sliceable
    return idx._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind='getitem')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 1407, in _convert_slice_indexer
    indexer = self.slice_indexer(start, stop, step, kind=kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py", line 1515, in slice_indexer
    return Index.slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind=kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3350, in slice_indexer
    kind=kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3538, in slice_locs
    start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, 'left', kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3487, in get_slice_bound
    raise err
KeyError: 1435802520000000000
```

I think it's a time-stamp conversion problem so I tried the following but still it wouldn't work :

```
d3 = pandas.Timestamp(datetime(Y, M, D, H, m))
d2 = pandas.to_datetime(d)
```

Your help would be appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: The error line you are refering (`subseries= df[d:f]`) doesnt not appear in your sample code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant to say.

Comment: I changed" df" to "series", my bad. Tried to change the initial variables' names of my code to make it clearer in this post.
Hope it's all good now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your code correctly, when you do this:

```
subseries = series['2015-07-07 01:00:00':'2015-07-07 03:30:00']
```

you're slicing `series` (btw, that's confusing seeing as there is a pandas datatype `Series`) from two strings.

if that works, then what you need from `subseries= df[d:f]` would be that `d` and `f` be strings.

you can do that by calling the datetime method `.strftime()` eg:

```
d= GetDatetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
f= GetDatetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 4):

change `def GetDatetime()` function return value to:

```
return str(d)
```

This will return datetime string which times series will be able to deal with.